How to get the PresentationSource for a Wpf MessageBox?
When I try to show a wpf System.Windows.MessageBox, I sometimes get the following exception.
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=This Visual is not connected to a PresentationSource.

I came across this SO answer where it recommends we get the PresentationSource and check it before showing up the MessageBox.
So the question is how? The following does not work.
System.Windows.PresentationSource.FromVisual(System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Lost Focus"));

The FromVisual Method above, expects a System.Windows.Media.Visual object. So how can we get the Visual object from System.Windows.MessageBox.Show method?
Or, are there any other ways to avoid the exception?
I get the exception in the following scenario.
I show the message box in the Lost Focus event handler of a user control, and it works fine. But when I try to close the user control itself, the lost focus handler is invoked, and at this time that exception is thrown. Am trying to avoid that exception.

The UC is trying to "go out of focus", but you're pinning it down with a "modal" dialog in the handler (IMO). Use a modeless Window; a "status line"; or do "it" somewhere else.

To get the PresentationSource for a WPF MessageBox, you can access the PresentationSource property of the Window that is internally created by the MessageBox when it is shown; however, directly accessing this property is not recommended as the MessageBox is a system-level dialog and its internal structure might change across versions

Hmm...By the time, the Window is shown, the exception is already thrown. Thats the problem.
